# For an ActiveRecord one-to-many association, which :foreign_key option should I set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

ActiveRecord's `has_many` and `belongs_to` methods both take a `:foreign_key` option. If I need to use it to handle a nonstandard FK column name, should I set it for the parent model (`has_many`), child model (`belongs_to`), or both, or does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `:foreign_key` option on both.

Consider the following two models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :foreign_key => "articleID"
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article, :foreign_key => "articleID"
end
```

Declaring `has_many` in the `Article` class allows you to do:

```
Article.find(12).comments  # Finds all comments with comment.articleID == 12
```

The `belongs_to` method call in the `Comment` model allows for:

```
Comment.last.article       # Finds article with article.id == comment.articleID
```

As you can see, in both cases the foreign key is used. If omitted in either location, that particular association proxy will not work properly.

Comment: You don't *always* need to set the `:foreign_key` option on both. In your particular example, you do, because you have a legacy column name. However, this issue comes up a lot when you're just renaming an association, i.e., `belongs_to :default_account, :class_name => "Account", :foreign_key => "account_id"`. The corresponding `has_one` in the Account class does not need to specify the foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

`belongs_to` guesses the foreign key to be the association name plus `_id`.

`has_one` guesses the foreign key to be the name of the containing class plus `_id`.

Usually for a nonstandard key, you only need it in one place.

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Rails default fk is isbn_id
  belongs_to :isbn, :class_name => "BarCode", :foreign_key => "bar_code_id" 
end

class BarCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Rails default fk is bar_code_id, so you don't need to specify it
  has_one :book
end
```